# Why does java.util.ArrayList allow to add null?

Tags: java, api-design, collections

I wonder why `java.util.ArrayList` allows to add `null`.  Is there any case where I would want to add `null` to an `ArrayList`?

I am asking this question because in a project we had a bug where some code was adding `null` to the `ArrayList` and it was hard to spot where the bug was. Obviously a `NullPointerException` was thrown but not until other code tried to access the element. The problem was how to locate the code that added the `null` object. It would have been easier if `ArrayList` threw an exception in the code where the elements was being added.

Comment: The [Guava Project](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a [pretty interesting page on that topic](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) (they don't allow `null` in most of their collections).

Comment: I believe that the answers given here cover well the question. Maybe one thing that should be mentioned is: don't take everything that's in the JDK as holly and perfect, and then whack your head trying to understand why it is so "perfect". Some things are (honest, IMHO) mistakes, that remained there due to backwards compatibility and that's that. Even the Java creators admit it, just read Joshua Bloch's books to see his critique of certain Java APIs. At any rate, your question comes down to weather there isn't a more elegant way to catch NPE in Java. The answer is, no, but there should be.

Comment: Can you provide more information on why it should not be allowed? If it is just a matter of taste, then the less restrictive should be prefered.

Comment: The simple answer is just that `null` is the default way to represent missing data in Java, whether you like it or not. In fact a lot of people don't like it and make it an argument for functional programming-style things. The most upvoted answer makes no sense/doesn't capture the essence of the issue.

Comment: @JIXiang You're oversimplifying what `null` is. "Missing" is just one of several potential interpretations of `null`. Other valid interpretations could be "Unknown," "Not Applicable," or "Uninitialized." What `null` represents depends on the application. As the Python community would say, "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess." Refusing to hold null in a container that is perfectly capable of doing so would be just that--a guess.

Comment: Why was it hard to spot where the bug was? It sounds like the easiest thing in the world - identify methods which modify this ArrayList; make them check for null.

Comment: Null values are used universally in Java, throughout literally billions of lines of code, to mean whatever the hell the developer needed null to mean. If you think "all* nulls are bad, you need to use a different language. But java allows nulls, so they not only could but added to lists, but *should* be added to lists in contexts where null is valid. If you disagree, then good luck representing a List of method arguments without using null.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This design decision appears mostly driven by naming.

Name **ArrayList** suggests to reader a functionality similar to **arrays** - and it is natural for [Java Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) designers to expect that vast majority of API users will rely on it functioning similar to arrays.

This in particular, involves treatment of null elements. API user knowing that below works OK:

```
array[0] = null; // NPE won't happen here
```

would be [quite surprised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) to find out if similar code for ArrayList would throw NPE:

```
arrayList.set(0, null); // NPE => WTF?
```

Reasoning like above is presented in [JCF tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html) stressing points that suggest close similarity between ArrayList and plain arrays:

> ArrayList... offers **constant-time positional access and is just plain fast**...

If you would want a List implementation disallowing nulls, it would better be called like `NonNullableArrayList` or something like that, to avoid confusing API users.

---

Side note there is an auxiliary discussion in comments below, along with **[additional considerations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mejbq.png)** supporting the reasoning laid out here.

Comment: This explanation is not convincing, considering that `LinkedList` *also* supports `null` list entries.

Comment: @StephenC LinkedList could get this "transitively" so to speak, once designers decided that they want null entries to be supported by particular List implementation, they could push this to other implementations as a matter of consistency. Rephrasing self, "API user knowing that `arrayList.set(0, null)` works OK, would be quite surprised to find out if similar code for LinkedList would throw NPE"

Comment: Yea ... but a simpler and (IMO) more plausible explanation is that allowing `null` entries is useful in a lot of cases.

Comment: ArrayList isn't called like that because it mimics an array.  It is called like that because it is a list implemented as an array.  Just as a TreeMap doesn't behave like a Tree.

Comment: This answer, IMO, is just plain wrong.  Nulls are allowed because in Java, for better or worse, (IMO, worse) null gets used a lot to represent uninitialized or missing values.  How did it get the most votes and the "accept" check?  Seriously, I'm really losing faith in StackOverflow these days.

Comment: @FlorianF exposing underlying data structure in the name (when done right) sets right expectations of API users. Using your own example, knowing that mapping goes to tree helps to understand "guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations" ([javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html))

Comment: @user949300 nice theory about wide usage of null being the reason, but I guess you didn't post it as an [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) because you found nothing to [back it up](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/1110/31260)? FWIW I also considered this when doing research before answering, and had to drop exactly for this reason, found nothing to back it up

Comment: @gnat - A quick Google search finds many articles about nulls, including this quote: "A wise man once said you are not a real Java programmer until you've dealt with a null pointer exception. Joking aside, the null reference is the source of _many_ problems."  It is undeniable that nulls are commonly used /misused in Java.  Or do you want evidence that the designers of Collections specifically allowed nulls because they were common?   Can't provide that directly, but I believe they designers of Collections were smart, and might have avoided nulls if they were not so darned common.

Comment: @user949300 correct. I couldn't make a compelling general case for wide usage of null being the reason (if memory serves this was because API docs allow collections rejecting null, and do so without any reservations). Nor could I find that this was the case for ArrayList

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. This is just unsupported guesswork about nulls being allowed in a list implementation. Here is a [roundup](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/LivingWithNullHostileCollections) of Java collections allowing/disallowing nulls; notice how it has *nothing* to do with similarity to arrays.

Comment: @AndresF. re-read the very _roundup_ you refer, it makes a pretty strong connection with arrays with the explanation that `null` is "unavoidable in object arrays". You may call it guesswork as much as you want, but in a collection intended _by name_ to resemble API user behavior of plain arrays, keeping the similarity in treating nulls perfectly fits within [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

Comment: very irrelevant example presented. First of all, who told u that arraylist.set(0,null) throws Runtime Ex because you are trying to set a null value at an index? Runtime Ex is thrown because set() works only for existing indexes, and you may have tried to set on an arraylist which doesn't have any value at index 0 yet. add() and set() are different methods, and set() cannot substitute add() functionality. In case of arrays, assignments are ambiguous, means it doesn't matter you are adding a new value or overwriting existing one. The example provided has no relevance to the question.

Comment: many (almost all) of the prior comments were useful and I [addressed all of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mejbq.png). The only comment I didn't address is the [last one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163489/why-does-java-util-arraylist-allow-to-add-null/163492#comment618616_163492 "'very irrelevant example etc...'") and this is because I couldn't make any sense of it no matter how I tried

Answer (score 33):

Null may be a valid value for an element of a list.  Say your list contains elements which represent some optional data about a list of users and is stored in the same order as the users.  If the extra data is populated then your list will contain the additional data otherwise the slot corresponding to a user will be null.  (I'm sure there are better examples, but you get the idea)

if you don't want to allow nulls to be added then you could wrap the array list with your own wrapper which threw when null was added.

Comment: That seems like a bad example of why nulls should be allowed -- there's better ways of representing optional data than using null values in a list.

Comment: @casablanca yeah totally agree, its not a great example.

Comment: I can't find a good reason for a ArrayList to contain nulls, other then bad surprises for the next developer to 'discover' it :/

Comment: @casablanca  While I agree with you that nulls should be avoided for representing optional data, in Java, for better or worse, that is "traditional".

Comment: @casablanca That is indeed a bad use of nulls, but one that is often used in practice in Java-land.

Comment: A solid use-case: You want to pass the parameters to some dynamic function as a list. You have several functions, each with a different set of parameters, so you need a dynamically sized array and you can always pass null as a valid function argument!

Answer (score 21):

`ArrayList` allows null by design.  It is intentional.  From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> "[ArrayList is a] resizable-array implementation of the List interface. Implements all optional list operations, and permits all elements, **including null**."

The answer to "why" is that if it didn't the ArrayList wouldn't be usable in cases where it is necessary to put a `null` in the list.  By contrast, you can prevent an ArrayList from containing nulls by either testing values before adding them or using a wrapper that prevents this happening.

> Is there any case where I would want to add null to an ArrayList?

Obviously, any case where `null` has a distinct meaning.  For instance it might mean that the value at a given position in the list has not been initialized or supplied.

> It would have been easier if the ArrayList had thrown an exception in the code where the elements was being added.

You could easily implement that behaviour by creating a wrapper class.  However, this is not the behaviour that *most* programmers / applications need.

Answer (score 8):

*Is there any case where I would want to add null to an ArrayList?*

Sure, what about pre-allocation? You want an `ArrayList` of things you can't create yet because you don't have enough info. Just because you can't think of a reason why someone may want to do something doesn't make it a bad idea. Whatever. (Now, I'm sure someone will come along and say you should instead have empty objects that fulfill some pattern they read about on some obscure blog and that programmers should really be able to write programs without ever using `if` statements, blah blah.)

If you guys have a contract that there never should be `null`s in a container then it's up to you lot to make sure that contract is upheld, probably most appropriately by asserting. It would probably have taken you max 10 lines of code. Java makes it incredibly easy for you to do this sort of thing. The JDK cannot read your mind.

Comment: Your preallocation argument is invalid, because this is already build into ArrayList with the `ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)` method and the `ArrayList(int initialCapacity)` constructor.

Comment: @Philipp What values will it put into that space?

Comment: The obvious choice is to put a `null` in the pre-allocated (but as yet _unused_) entries of the `ArrayList`; but we can let `ensureCapacity` do that and yet not allow other functions such as `set` to do it. The reasons given elsewhere seem stronger.

Comment: @DavidK: It makes sense to say that it should be possible to `set` an item to any value which could be returned by `get`.  Even if a normal attempt to `get` an item for which space had been allocated but never written should throw an exception rather than returning `null`, it would still be useful to have a pair of methods that would allow `list1.setOrEraseIfNull(index, list2.getOrReturnNull(index))` rather than requiring `if (list2.valueSet(index)) list1.set(index, list2.get(index)); else list1.unset(index);`

Comment: @supercat I agree that `null` is a useful value. I do not even suggest that the API be rewritten to forbid it. I meant to say only that while there _are_ persuasive reasons for allowing `null`, the preallocation argument is not among them. (I don't even mean to say it's a bad idea--if you can append _one_ `null` to a list, why not a larger number, _for reasons "given elsewhere."_)

Comment: @DavidK: Attempting to read an entry which has been allocated but not yet written must either yield null or throw an exception; it's easier to have it return null.

Comment: @supercat Here is an example of "pre-allocation" as I understand it: we have an `ArrayList` named `a`. At some point during a run, when `a.size() == 20`, we call `a.ensureCapacity(100)`. At this point we are assured that memory locations for `a[20]` through `a[99]` have been allocated, but the API says that the expression `a[20]` would throw an exception. Do you object to this feature of the API? The API _does_ allow you to increase the size of `a` by appending several `null` elements; in this example we can add at least 80 such elements without allocating any memory.

Comment: @DavidK: Sorry--I mostly use .NET rather than Java and thought the earlier poster was referring to a method analogous to the `SetLength` method of `StringBuilder`, but it seems `ArrayList` doesn't seem to have one.  Somewhat curious, given that such a feature would make `ArrayList` more array-like.

Comment: @supercat Ah, that makes sense. I admit I was a bit surprised by the lack of a method to increase the size of the `ArrayList`. Perhaps someone else can explain it. :-)

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be more of a (software-)philosophic question here.

`ArrayList` as a utility class is designed to be helpful in a wide context of possible use-cases.

Contrary to your hidden claim that accepting null as a valid value should be discouraged, there are many examples where the null value is perfectly legal.

The single most important reason is that `null` is the `do not know` equivalent of any reference type, including framework types. This implies that null cannot be replaced in any case by a more fluent version of the `nothing` value.

So, lets say you store the Integers 1, 3, 7 in your arraylist at its corresponding index:
Due to some computation, you want to get the element at index 5, so what your array
should return is: "no value stored". This could be achieved through returning null
or a [NullObject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). In most cases returning the built in null value is expressive
enough. After calling a method that *can* return null and using its return value a check of the returned value against null is quite common in modern code.

Answer (score 4):

The statement

```
File f = null;
```

is valid and useful (I don't think I need to explain why). It is likewise useful to have a collection of files, some of which may be null.

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
// use my collection of files
// ....
// not using this one anymore:
files.set(3, null);
```

The usefulness of collections that may contain null objects proceeds directly from the usefulness of objects that may be null. It is really as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to accept everything, than to be to be restrictive and then try opening up your design after the fact.

For example, what if they oracle/sun provided only NonNullableArrayList, but you wanted to be able to add a Null to your list.  How would you do it?  You would probably have to create an entirely different object, you couldn't use extend the NonNullableArrayList.  Instead if you have a ArrayList that takes everything, you could easily extend it, and override the add, where it doesn't accept null values.

Comment: Disagreed. Allowing too much is harder to correct once the misfeature has seen widespread use. If language designers allowed nulls at a later stage, it wouldn't break existing programs, but the opposite is not true.

Comment: But I agree.  It is about maximizing functionality.  You can use a list that accepts nulls even you don't need them.  You cannot use a list that refuses nulls if you need nulls.

Answer (score -1):

Usefullness of null?

Very much so when you go with a **List of Lists to model a 2D real life plate** with different positions. Half of those positions could be empty (in random coordinates) while the filled ones don't represent a simple *int* or *String* but are represented by a complex object. If you want to keep the positional info, you need to fill the empty spots with null so that your *list.get(x).get(y)* doesn't lead to nasty surprises. To counter the null exceptions you can check for null (very popular) or you can use an Optional (which I find handy in this case). The alternative would be to fill the empty spots with "junk" objects which can lead to all kinds of mess down the road. If your null check fails or is forgotten somewhere, Java will let you know. On the other hand a "junk" placeholder object which is not checked properly may pass unnoticed.